# django-lean: Introducing new template tags

Tags: django, jinja2, django-templates, django-lean

I am working on a project which is based on open-source. It's call [askbot](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel). I wanted to add a/b testing to it and after doing some research I found out [django-lean](https://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-lean/wiki/Home). I am not an expert in django but I manage to bring the strip down version of the django-lean to my version of askbot-dlevel. I used the [blog post](http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/15951774761/ab-split-testing-django). But my problem is that I am getting following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/
Encountered unknown tag 'experiment'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/questions/
Django Version: 1.4.10
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Encountered unknown tag 'experiment'.
```

Just to give more information how I incorporate django-lean: As the blog-post mention I only use the experiments module:

I added experiments folder from django-lean inside askbot folder and expose it as another install-app using settings file. So now it looks like another application.

I copied experiments.py and smartif.py to askbot-dlevel/templatetags because thats the right thing to do based on he [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

In askbot-dlevel there is a utils folder and in that there is decorators.py, I added the following:

```
def set_experiment_user(view_func):
    '''Decorator for setting the WebUser for use with ab split testing assumes
    first argument is the request object'''
    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        WebUser(request).confirm_human()
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Now as mentioned in the blog-post I added following to my view:

```
@csrf.csrf_protect
@decorators.set_experiment_user
def ask_widget(request, widget_id):

    def post_question(data, request):
        thread = models.Thread.objects.create_new(**data)
        question = thread._question_post()
        request.session['widget_question_url'] = question.get_absolute_url()
        return question

    widget = get_object_or_404(models.AskWidget, id=widget_id)
    ...
```

and in my template just as the blog post mentioned I did the following:

and in the template, I have done the following:

```
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}

{% load experiments %}
{% experiment experiment_name top_contributors %}
{% if contributors and settings.SIDEBAR_MAIN_SHOW_AVATARS %}
    {% include "widgets/contributors.html" %}
{% endif %}
{% endexperiments %}
```

as this point as the blog post mention things should work. Using the admin console I have created and experiment and the name of the experiment is top_contributors. And if things run all users would be in the experiment. But I am getting above mention error which tells me template tags have not been registered.

askbot-dlevel project uses jinja2 (I think) but looks like blog-post has written its template code in regular django template mode. Could this be an issue? How can I convert this to jinja if thats the case. If not what am I missing here?

To best of my knowledge I tried to convert what blog-post written into jinja2:

```
{% if experiments.experiment('top_contributors') %}
{% if contributors and settings.SIDEBAR_MAIN_SHOW_AVATARS %}
    {% include "widgets/contributors.html" %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

After this I get following error:

```
UndefinedError at /questions/
'experiments' is undefined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/questions/
Django Version: 1.4.10
Exception Type: UndefinedError
Exception Value:    
'experiments' is undefined
Exception Location: ..python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py in getattr, line 397
Python Executable:  ../ABFrameWork/bin/python
```

Comment: Why have you copied templatetags from `django-lean` app? What if you remove `experiments.py` and `smartif.py` from your templatetags package? Have you followed the installation procedure described [here](https://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-lean/wiki/Home#!installation)?

Comment: @alecxe I removed them from akbot/templatetags and kept it in askbot/experiments/templatetags but same error. Yes I have followed instructions. My instructions are more inline with blog-post because I am only bringing in experiments folder in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do migrate before running the server.